# How to handle global loading screen on multiple API calls in React-js/React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, es6-promise

I maintained one redux value call isLoading for the loading screen. I am putting isLoading=true before calling to the API then set it as false on catch and after getting the result. It's working fine. My problem is when I am using multiple API calls.

assume we have 3 API calls. If 1st API fetched data after 2sec, it will be set isLoading into false. but still 2nd and 3rd API's fetching data. how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Promise all method for this...

```
const promise1 = firstApiCall();
const promise2 = secondApiCall();
const promise3 = thidApiCall();

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
  // and you can switch here to isLoading to false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the reducer to a counter. For each LOADING action increment the counter, and for DONE action decrement it. Create a simple selector that return `true` if the counter is greater than 0 (loading):

```js
const { createStore } = Redux

function loadingReducer(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOADING':
      return state + 1
    case 'DONE':
      return state - 1
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const store = createStore(loadingReducer)

const isLoading = state => state > 0

store.dispatch({ type: 'LOADING' })
store.dispatch({ type: 'LOADING' })

console.log(isLoading(store.getState()))

store.dispatch({ type: 'DONE' })
store.dispatch({ type: 'LOADING' })
console.log(isLoading(store.getState()))

store.dispatch({ type: 'DONE' })
store.dispatch({ type: 'DONE' })
console.log(isLoading(store.getState()))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.0-beta.1/redux.min.js" integrity="sha512-lbCmhqdlJjTzzRbvaHugWpmoDmdqrFW/kmnKyNJH9NiXjKECwiPG6LYc9/iHveXIMyQpMWTo6J8gQXOrmkbe3A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```